# How to resolve outgoing .xyz email marked as spam?

Tags: email, exchange

We are running a custom domain ending in .xyz through Exchange, and are being told that a lot of our externally sent mail is going to people's junk/spam.

We have MX and TXT records on the domain (Route53), and have asked people to forward false positive junk to not_junk@office365.microsoft.com.

The IT team seems to think that it's a blanket issue with .xyz domains and that's why we're being flagged for junk. Is there anything we can do to bolster our email validity?

Comment: Try using a mail sender like Constant Contact or Mail Chimp instead of doing this yourself in Exchange.

Comment: Unless you can provide info on how/why the messages are being diverted then there isn't much we can offer except opinions. Start on the recipient end and check the headers etc.  If these emails are being sent to large numbers of recipients without including the standard anti-spam measures that bulk mailers use (e.g. opt-in, unsubscribe link, etc.) then it isn't surprising they would be classified as suspected spam.

Comment: Does the issue occur to internal recipients or external recipients? If it’s the external recipients, are they all external recipients or specific recipients?

Comment: @BlindSpots these are always external emails to one or two specific recipients. Just usual business email. The format is always something like "Hey, great to chat earlier, here is the stuff we spoke about" etc...

Comment: @Faery as above